# Почему в String.xml компиль ругается?

Tags: xml, android

```
<integer-array name="asd">
    <item>R.drawable.cocktail1</item>
</integer-array>
```

Почему в String.xml компиль ругается на то, что нельзя вписать в `<item></item>`  `R.drawable.cocktail1`? Ведь `R.drawable.cocktail1` - это целое число, а может быть, правильнее идентификатор объекта, но в виде целого числа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы путаете java и xml, смешивая их в одну кучу. R.drawable.cocktail1 - это константа, определенная внутри вашего java-файла и известная только в рамках ваших java-классов. xml же ни о каких сущностях внутри вашего кода, разумеется, знать не знает, и поэтому для него это R.drawable.cocktail1 выглядит исключительно как некая строка, не более

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя синтаксис java пихать в xml. Нужно это делать программно.

Вот тут все для твоего случая [описано](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064595/get-an-integer-array-from-an-xml-resource-in-android-program). Но, как по мне, проще делать примерно так:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al.add(0);
    al.add(1);
    al.add(5);
    al.add(4);
    al.add(3);
    java.util.Collections.sort(al);//for sorting Integer values

    String listString = "";

    for (int s : al)
    {
        listString += s + " ";
    }
    nameofile.setText(listString);
```